# How to pass in params with RSpec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to test the following:

```
book_content = params[:chapter][:markdown_format]
```

How would I pass in the `params[:chapter][:markdown_format]` with the following RSpec controller test:

`put :update_book, id: book.id, book: book`

Comment: Just pass it.  `put :update_book, id: book.id, book: book, chapter: {markdown_format: 'test'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
put :update_book, id: book.id, book: book, chapter: { markdown_format: 'pdf rtf or something you want' }
```

P.S. Why do you pass the `book` (which is variable I think) to the parameters?

I think you need to do something like this:

```
put :update_book, id: book.id, book: { chapter: { markdown_format: 'pdf rtf or docx' } }
```

This is usual CRUD operation